# can we send image push notifications using fcm in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am unable to send images as push notification in flutter

I am using firebase_messaging package. can it be done using flutter

Comment: I assume you can do this using https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_local_notifications

Comment: Push messages have a size restriction, so you won't be able to send an image (not a flutter thing, a general thing). As mentioned, you should send either a URL for download or other identifier to flutter so it can retrieve the image. However, this is not specific to flutter and very much depends on your server implementation. We may be able to give some help with that, but it's fairly off-topic as it doesn't have so much to do with flutter as your infrastructure.

Comment: Did you found any solution for this? @praveen?

Answer (score 1):

You can send Image URL in the notification payload and then fetch the image in the device using the received the URL. I guess this is the best way you can do it.

Comment: Can you please share what you are passing in the notification while sending?

Comment: i want to send image along with data like flipkart,amazon notification

Answer (score 0):

I use example code of flutter_local_notifications pub and success show Notification with large icon or bigPicture. In below example I only show largeIcon, if you want to show bigPicture, you need to use styleInformation instead.

```
Future<String> _downloadAndSaveFile(String url, String fileName) async {
final Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
final String filePath = '${directory.path}/$fileName';
final http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
final File file = File(filePath);
await file.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);
return filePath;
}

Future<void> _showLocalNotification(CustomNotification notification) async {
if (!notification.image!.isNullOrEmpty) {
  _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
    notification.id,
    notification.title,
    notification.body,
    NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          _channel.id,
          _channel.name,
          channelDescription: _channel.description,
          importance: Importance.max,
          priority: Priority.high,
          enableVibration: true,
          color: AppColor.colorPrimary,
          icon: '@drawable/ic_vota',
          largeIcon: FilePathAndroidBitmap(await _downloadAndSaveFile(
              notification.image ?? '', 'largeIcon')),
        ),.....
```

And the payload look like this

```
{
"to": "fcm-token",
"data": {
    "body": "",
    "title": "",
    "imageUrl": ""
},
"notification": {
    "body": "",
    "title": ""
}
}
```

If you want to use both largeIcon & bigPicture, watch this

```
final String largeIconPath =
    await _downloadAndSaveFile('online image URL', 'largeIcon');
final String bigPicturePath = await _downloadAndSaveFile(
    'online image URL', 'bigPicture');

final BigPictureStyleInformation bigPictureStyleInformation =
 BigPictureStyleInformation(FilePathAndroidBitmap(bigPicturePath),
        largeIcon: FilePathAndroidBitmap(largeIconPath));

final AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
    AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'big text channel id', 'big text channel name',
        channelDescription: 'big text channel description',
        styleInformation: bigPictureStyleInformation);
```